# Arduino Serial - use start bit

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

My arduino uno should communicate with a serial port with the following configuration:

```
Baudrate = 9600
1 start bit
7 data bits
1 parity bit (even)
1 stop bit
```

Now I don't know how to configure it using `Serial.begin` so it will use the start bit. Without the start bit I would use `Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_7E1)`.

Comment: You might have better luck on the Arduino forums.

Answer (score 0):

1 start bit is the default for `Serial.begin()` as well as the underlying USART, and cannot be changed at all.

Comment: So `Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_7E1)` should just work? I tried this but it doesn't read anything. I guess my problem is somewhere else.